# Why is cmp( ) useful?

Tags: python

According to the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) and this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_cmp.htm),

`cmp() returns -1 if x < y`

and

`cmp() returns 0 if  x == y`

and

`cmp() returns 1 if  x > y`

The tutorial also said that

> cmp() returns the sign of the difference of two numbers

I don't really get what  *sign of the difference of two numbers* means. Doesn't that mean that it returns a value when the sign of numbers aren't equal? Since...

```
cmp(80, 100) :  -1      # both have positive sign.
cmp(180, 100) :  1      # both also have positive sign.
cmp(-80, 100) :  -1
cmp(80, -100) :  1
```

**Note: code from the tutorial.*

Despite my confusion in sign differences, I can't really think of why do we need a built-in function to return a value of -1 when x < y.

Isn't the function **`cmp( )`** easily implemented ? Is there any reason why Python creators keep `cmp( )` function, or is there any hidden usage of this Python's **`cmp( )`** function ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> ## Why cmp( ) is useful?

It isn't very useful, which is why it was deprecated (the builtin `cmp` is gone and builtin sorts no longer accept one in Python 3). [Rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) supplanted it:

```
object.__lt__(self, other)
object.__le__(self, other)
object.__eq__(self, other)
object.__ne__(self, other)
object.__gt__(self, other)
object.__ge__(self, other)
```

This allows the `<` symbol (and other symbols) to be overloaded comparison operators, enabling, for example, subset and superset comparisons of set objects.

```
>>> set('abc') < set('cba')
False
>>> set('abc') <= set('cba')
True
>>> set('abc') == set('cba')
True
>>> set('abc') >= set('cba')
True
>>> set('abc') > set('cba')
False
```

while it could enable the above, `cmp` wouldn't allow the following:

```
>>> set('abc') == set('bcd')
False
>>> set('abc') >= set('bcd')
False
>>> set('abc') <= set('bcd')
False
```

### Toy usage for `cmp`

Here's an interesting usage which uses its result as an index (it returns -1 if the first is less than the second, 0 if equal, and 1 if greater than):

```
def cmp_to_symbol(val, other_val):
    '''returns the symbol representing the relationship between two values'''
    return '=><'[cmp(val, other_val)]

>>> cmp_to_symbol(0, 1)
'<'
>>> cmp_to_symbol(1, 1)
'='
>>> cmp_to_symbol(1, 0)
'>'
```

According to the docs, you should treat cmp as if it wasn't there:

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

### `cmp` removed, equivalent operation

But you can use this as the equivalent:

```
(a > b) - (a < b)
```

in our little toy function, that's this:

```
def cmp_to_symbol(val, other_val):
    '''returns the symbol representing the relationship between two values'''
    return '=><'[(val > other_val) - (val < other_val)]
```

Comment: From [PEP 207](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/): "The main motivation comes from NumPy, whose users agree that A<B should return an array of elementwise comparison outcomes; they currently have to spell this as less(A,B) because A<B can only return a Boolean result or raise an exception."

Comment: Your bit about sets and `>=` doesn't really hold as `cmp` could return an appropriate result for those cases. It would not work for the the NumPy case mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @LeviMorrison PEP 207 is a very good point, I'll mention that later. Now - what would be the appropriate result for two sets with each differences and an intersection (for example  `set('ab')` and `set('bc')`)? These sets are not ordered, currently test `False` for equality, less than, and greater than, and `cmp` would thus have no reasonable result, to my current thinking.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that `>=` was intended to be a set operation when posting that. Honestly I don't think it is a good idea to do that -- I don't think that notation is used in set theory and isn't intuitive, at least to me -- but numpy's usage for element-wise comparisons seems fine. Maybe switch to a numpy example?

Comment: @LeviMorrison I will probably add a numpy example since you bring it up. I do enjoy curating my answers, so if you see others with anything you'd like me to add or criticisms, please leave a suggestion for improvement.

Answer (score 11):

> I don't really get what does it mean *sign of the difference of two numbers.*

This means: take the difference, and then the sign of that difference. For example, if `x` and `y` are two numbers:

- `x < y` => `x - y < 0` and the function returns -1.
- `x == y` => `x - y == 0` and the function returns 0.
- `x > y` => `x - y > 0` and the function returns 1.

For more information on three-way comparisons, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison).

Answer (score 3):

Trivalued comparators are very useful when sorting.  You don't just want to know whether two elements are equal; you also want to know their relative order so that you know how to rearrange them to move closer to a sorted list.  This is why C (`strcmp`) and Perl (`cmp`) both have similar operations (in those cases for strings, but it's the same idea).

Answer (score 2):

For sorting sequences of items. When you are sorting a list of items you only need to know one item is greater or less than another item.

More info here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#The_Old_Way_Using_the_cmp_Parameter

Answer (score 1):

> Another use case: **Finding the sign (- / +)** of a number

If you want to find out, what the sign (+/-) of a number is, you can easily use `0` as the second argument to the `cmp` function

```
cmp(-123, 0) #returns -1
cmp( 123, 0) #returns  1
```